# Why CSS position: sticky isn't applied?

Tags: html, css, sticky

A more direct title would read: "CSS position sticky does not work".

```css
#style-guide {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="style-guide">
                    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                        <nav id="style-guide-nav">
                            <div>this is the nav</div>
                            <div>this is the nav</div>
                            <div>this is the nav</div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div style="height: 500vh;">
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                        content content content content content content content content content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason why the code is so nested is that I have stripped away all the extraneous classes, styles, id, attributes, siblings, etc. from the production code.

The code doesn't seem to want to apply sticky positioning to the element. I thought it was because it was nested inside a grid, but a simple test proved that's not the case (unless I did something wrong there as well).

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I believe it is because the outer container uses `display: grid` (though I cannot find any mention of `sticky` within `grid` in the [CSS3 grid layout documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/). If you change the style of `#style-guide` to `display: block` then it works fine (on my Firefox 68 browser), though you'll need to adjust the styles of the other elements to compensate for the loss of grid layout mode.

Answer (score 1):

Simply move the CSS declaration to the child element. The `nav-wrapper` is having the same height as the div with content so there is no room for it to have a sticky position but its child can stick inside it.

Adding some border will make things more clear:

```css
#style-guide {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#style-guide-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#style-guide>* {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div id="style-guide">
          <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <nav id="style-guide-nav">
              <div>this is the nav</div>
              <div>this is the nav</div>
              <div>this is the nav</div>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div style="
    height: 500vh;
">
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
            content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default [alignment for grid items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) is `stretch`, which is making the `.nav-wrapper` element the full height of the grid. Because you haven't scrolled past the end of the `.nav-wrapper` element, it's content isn't appearing to "stick" to the top of the container.

The simple solution is to change the alignment so that the `.nav-wrapper` element isn't stretched to full height:

```css
#style-guide {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    align-self: start; /* don't stretch */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="style-guide">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <nav id="style-guide-nav">
        <div>this is the nav</div>
        <div>this is the nav</div>
        <div>this is the nav</div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  <div style="height: 500vh;">
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content
  </div>
</div>
```